# Why doesn't my regex work in bash "if"?

Tags: bash, files, regular-expression

Here is my code:

```
if [ -f /Applications/xml[0-9].pl ]
```

I also tried with `-f =~` and double brackets but none seem to work.

I first though that the regex might be faulty but I tried this.

```
echo h1 | sed 's/h[0-9]/h/'
```

And that worked. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

You can't test a file with a regex nor a glob like this. You have to iterate over the files :

```
for file in /Applications/xml[0-9].pl; do if [ -f "$file" ]; then ...
```

Answer (score 1):

bash expands the regular expression before evaluating the condition.  If your directory has three files by the name

```
/Applications/xml0.pl
/Applications/xml1.pl
/Applications/xml2.pl
```

your `if` statement looks to shell as

```
if [ -f /Applications/xml0.pl /Applications/xml1.pl /Applications/xml2.pl ]]
```

which is syntactically incorrect.  You will need to specify the filename completely when you want to look for its existence by using

```
for file in /Applications/xml[0-9].pl
do
    if [ -f ${file} ]
```

or if you can, use the `find` command to do whatever you want done with the file.